# PHP change existing array keys with another array value

Tags: php

I have this 2 array:

```
$array = [ 'one', 'two', 'three' ];

$anohter_array = [ 4, 6, 8 ];
```

Now, how can I change the variable `$array` keys to 4, 6, 8 instead of 0, 1, 2?

Answer (score -1):

$array = [4 => 'one', 'two', 'three' ];

Comment: I'm quite sure this is not what OP meant